# TTTAttributedLabel link font changing when UIAlertView presents

Tags: ios, uialertview, nsattributedstring, tttattributedlabel

I have a weird problem: I have a TTTAttributedLabel with a link in it:

[image]

The name "bryan"is the link. When a `UIAlertView` is presented over this label, the font of the link changes:

[image]

As you can see the link lost its font size and weight. Has anyone seen this before? Is there a separate font attribute for "link in background" or something? Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This happens when you create a link, then set `linkAttributes`. When the UIAlertController is presented the link becomes "inactive", and it reverts back to a default style. Setting `inactiveLinkAttributes` fixed this.

Source: https://github.com/TTTAttributedLabel/TTTAttributedLabel/issues/542

Comment: This literally saved my life. I used [:] for inactiveLinkAttributes as thinking it is not necessary for me. Drove me crazy to find what the problem is when a popover or alertView is presented. Ah man